# How can i make User Selection Courier service

Tags: magento-1.9

I need user should be select the courier service at the shipping proces, like aramax, professional, DHL, FedEx,

Answer (score 0):

There is no by default **courier service** shipping method in Magento.
You need to create custom shipping for this, there are several tutorial available.

[Here is a very good tutorial by Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/) also See [Here.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/)

You can download the module by Inchoo from here 
https://github.com/udovicic/Magento_Custom_Shipping

Then customize it according to your need.

Comment: Here is a very good tutorial by Inchoo  --   this link not working, could you give me valid url

Comment: updated the link plz check .

Comment: added download link check this one

Comment: Make sure, user can select desired courier service like fedex, professional, dhl, and their cost.

Comment: You have to customize according to you need this is the only a way how you can do.

Comment: okay, let me check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40478/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-arunendra).